# Incorrect app name is shown in location authorisation alert in mac OS X app

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, cllocationmanager

My mac OS X app has **dev** and **uat** schemes. I have modified product name in target build settings to display $(TARGET_NAME)_dev for development configuration and $(TARGET_NAME)_uat for uat configuration.

On launch of **dev** scheme, it displays **xyz_dev** and **xyz_uat** for **uat** scheme as expected.

My mac OS X app uses `CLLocationManger` to fetch latitude and longitude values. The issue is, on launch of **dev** scheme, it displays "xyz_uat would like to use your current location" in location authorisation alert. Similarly it displays "xyz_dev would like to use your current location" for **uat** scheme.

Could any one pls help in figuring out the reason for incorrect app name being displayed in location authorisation alert while launching different schemes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the .plist files that you are using for both of those schemes; it looks like the strings used for the alert are are in the wrong .plist

Comment: PRODUCT_NAME is the variable you need

Comment: @Mike Hay - My .plist doesn't contain any info regarding location authorisation alert. This alert is shown when CLLocationmanger object is created

Comment: @Marek H - Yes, Respective PRODUCT_NAME's value for relavent scheme in location authorisation alert

Comment: It may help to look at ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_always_authorization ) which states 

"You are required to include the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` keys in your app's Info.plist file. (If your app supports iOS 10 and earlier, the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key is also required.) "

Comment: @MikeHay - As mentioned above, mine is mac OS X app, so its not needed to add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription keys in info.plist